# page opens in new tab instead left frame

Tags: html, hyperlink, frames

I can't open link in the other frame. Here's an `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="icon" href="b.png" type="image/png">
<title>Free as in Beer</title>
<frameset cols="85%,15%">
  <frame src="left.html" name="leftside" >
  <frame src="right.html" name="rightside" >
</frameset>
</head>
</html>
```

`left.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/default.css">
    <script src="highlight.pack.js"></script>
    <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
  </head>
  <h1><a name="bio">Bio</a></h1>
    <pre><code class="bash">bk-simulates-range.py -S "" -b "" -e "" -s "" -t dspc.top -n 3000000 -c -j bk-runs-mpi.bash -w "-4.5.5-double_gcc"

bk-pymol-selects.py -f confout.gro -s "resi 1-128" -t traj.trr -i 50

bk-pymol-selects.py -f *ane.gro bk-pymol-pic.py -f confout.gro -s "resi 1-128" -x "-2" -y "-3" -z "0" -t traj.trr

bk-clean-dirs.py "(.*ane.gro$|.*itp$|.*top$|.*tpr$)"

rm bkLog confout.gro *.cpt md.mdp; rename 's/^.(.+)...$/$1/' \#* && rm \#*</code></pre>
  <hr>
  <!-- hhmts start -->Last modified: Fri Feb  3 21:40:01 MSK 2012 <!-- hhmts end -->
  </body>
</html>
```

and `right.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
      p {
      font-family : DejaVu Sans Mono;
      font-size : 12pt;
      line-height : 120%;
      margin-top : 0px;
      margin-bottom : 0px;
      white-space : pre-wrap;
      display : inline;
      }
      h1 {
      font-size : 14pt;
      line-height : 100%;
      margin-top : 20px;
      margin-bottom : -1px;
      display : block;
      color : blue ; 
      }
    </style>
<body link=ff8700>
<body vlink=ff8700>
<body alink=ff8700>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Notes</h1>
<p><a href="m.html#bio" target="leftside">Bio</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Couldn't be simpler - yet it doesn't work: When I push on the Bio at the right frame - it opens in the new tab - instead of the left frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be down to your local browser 'open in a new tab' settings?

Comment: This behaviour was caused by the "Lock tab" Firefox's functionality (right click on tab to toggle it).